# Find Word files with specific page total

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, find

I'm using Windows 7 and I'm hunting my filesystem for a Word file that was most probably created on the 4th of April, 2011. However, I can't be sure of this; the only thing I am sure of is that it is 9 pages in total (I have a printed copy which proves this). Is there any way that I can do a Word - specific search in order to find only Word documents that have 9 pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a printed copy of the Word document, do a Windows search for a specific phrase that's in the document.  If you know the file type (.docx?), the search will be quicker.

Comment: While this is the most sensible option, it really should have been a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Date Modified Search tool in windows file explorer and enter the date of 4th April 2011. Try searching for different dates which you think could be probable.